# Is $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \log^3 n}$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Is $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \log^3 n}$$ absolutely convergent?

Using comparison test, since $n$ is greater than or equal to 3: $$\frac{1}{n^2 \log^3 n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

And, we know $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ converges by p-test.

Therefore, $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \log^3 n}$$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question.  Your proof is correct.

Note that in this case "absolutely convergent" is just the same as "convergent" since all the terms are positive.

Comment: oops i was suppose to ask if what I did is right or not. what about for conditionally convergent?

Comment: A conditionally convergent series is simply a convergent series which does not converge absolutely.  Since this series *does* converge absolutely, it cannot converge conditionally.  The two are mutually exclusive.  (In general, any series is exactly one of (1) divergent, (2) conditionally convergent, and (3) absolutely convergent.)